# Stability of an equilibrium

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

From a Center-Manifold reduction I get the following system:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}\dot x \\\dot y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-y(2x^2-2xy+y^2)\\x\end{pmatrix} $$
The aim is to analyze the stability of the origin. Using Matlab I had the impression that the origin is unstable. My idea was to introduce the time-reverse system $$ \begin{pmatrix}\dot x \\\dot y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y(2x^2-2xy+y^2)\\-x\end{pmatrix} $$ which appears to be asymptotically stable (Matlab). Unfortunately I didn't manage to find a Lyapunov-function and as far as I know it's the only possibility to proof stability of a non-hyperbolic equilibrium.
Any advice or a different approach is welcome :D